# Cannot Select Between No error can someonehelp me check string?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to input date value  in textbox1 and textbox2 but i think im not sure about string cmd can someone help me check issuse ? please

```
   try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            int tp;
            string sqlstr = "select * from viewReC_store where stk_date_time between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, con);
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = sdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label4.Text = "ERROR"+ex ;
        }
        con.Close();
```

> Blockquote               string sqlstr = "select * from viewReC_store where stk_date_time between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

i guess this line

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: NO any error just not working on me click btn

Comment: Try to return `sqlstr` and run it in your SQL Server to see if you get any rows or not.

Comment: can run in sql server no any error

Comment: You have made use of `text box's` to capture date and this can lead to unexpected results unless the `date` is not in the exact format SQL expects it to be. Try altering you `sqlstr` to this. **`select * from viewReC_store where stk_date_time between CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + TextBox1.Text + "', 102) and CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + TextBox2.Text + "', 102)"`**

Comment: Do you get any rows? If not so you cannot expect to get any rows in your application.

Comment: thank isolve my problem susses

Answer (score 0):

ok im  got it

```
           string sqlstr = "select * from viewReC_storeFG where stk_date_time between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
```

thank u for read and reply

close..